# Rails Joins and Like?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, join, squeel

I am trying to use joins in rails to retrieve some info base on a search field but I cannot seem to find the good syntax,
I have two table savings and product and saving are saving for a product. What I want is to find a saving based on the name of the product I found that this work :
    Saving.all(:joins => :product, :conditions => { :products => { :title => 'Title Name' } })
It retrieve the saving corresponding to the product named Title Name.

Now how can I change that to find the savings where product title contains  params[:title] ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Saving.joins{product}.where{(savings.products.title =~ my{"%#{params[:term]}%"} } with squeel
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Saving.joins(:product).where('products.title like ?', "%#{params[:title]}%")
```

Comment: Thanks, now i'm trying to do that with squeel so I did that :       Saving.joins{product}.where{savings.products.title =~ my{params[:term]} } which is working with the full title but I don't know how to make the request work with part of the title name. thanks